# Google Play Console Rejections

Tags: android, flutter, crash, google-play-console, mobile-application

My flutter application gets rejected for no minimal functionality. I have tested it many times it doesnt crashes. but google rejects the application for crash. What is the mistake iam doing

I uploaded my Application to the Google Play console for review it gets rejected for crashing.(No minimal functionality issues).

Comment: Did you test the release versio? Have you tried in on different devices? You can for example use the Firebase test lab to run it on devices in the cloud.

Comment: You should try monkey testing: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html or check the prelaunch tests that google is running with your release. Reports of those should be available in the play store console.

Answer (score 0):

release the app on `internal testing` track first then check `pre launch reports` it will show you crash logs, screenshots and video recording of the crash. this is very useful and will help you fix this.